# Rstudio snippet editor glitching, making it extremely difficult to edit snippets

Tags: r, rstudio, editor, code-snippets

I'm having issues with Rstudio, where I'm trying to edit my code snippets, but when I go to Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Edit Snippets.., the snippet editor opens up with the window behind the global options pop-up, while the text for the editor shows up in front of the global options pop up. I'm using R version 4.0.2, and I've tried deleting and re-downloading R and R studio, as well as restarting my session. I'll include a picture of my issue:

[image]

also, here's my session info

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2   rsconnect_0.8.16 tools_4.0.2      yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with R itself. What is your version of RStudio? My guess is that you have an issue with your graphics card/driver.

Answer (score 1):

Setting rendering engine to 'Desktop OpenGL' solved this for me.

[image]